# Is this function $3n+1=2^mk$ surjective?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

I'm trying to figure out whether this function $F:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ defined by $F(n)=m$ is surjective or not. The function $F(n)=m$ has $n\in \mathbb{N}$ where $m$ is a non-negative integer for which $3n+1=2^mk$, and $k$ is an odd integer.

So far, I have used this expression $3n=2^mk-1$ where $m\geq0$. What I found was that for most $m\ \text{and} \ k$, the output for $n$ would not be divisible by 3. Though I did find that for certain values, $$2^3\times5-1=39=13\times3=0\pmod{3}$$.

So my question is: is this function $F$ then surjective?

Comment: What about $2^5\times 5-1$?

Comment: "What I found was that for most m and k, the output for n
would not be divisible by 3."  Well that answers your question right there doesn't it?  If there exist **any** such m and k then this function is not surjective.

Comment: This problem looks like it arose from considering the Collatz conjecture. Is that what you're working on?

Comment: @user247327, that certainly does *not* answer the question. Finding values of $k$ for which it doesn't work does not in any way show that there is no value of $k$ for which it does.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs its a homework set that was given after completing the chapter on Functions for Discrete Mathematics. I am not so clear on what the Collatz Conjecture is because only 3 hours was dedicated to the entire chapter of functions.

Comment: @wsh_97, I see. I'll bet whoever wrote the question had Collatz in mind. This is exactly the sort of thing you think about when you work on that. I hope my answer is helpful; if it needs clarification, please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Let $m$ be a positive integer, we wish to know whether $2^m$, times some odd number, is of the form $3n+1$. If $m$ is even, then there is not much work to do. We know that any even power of $2$, minus $1$, is a multiple of $3$. (This is clear because $2^2=4\equiv 1\pmod 3$).

Now, odd powers of $2$ are of the form $3k+2$, so let's multiply this by an arbitrary odd number, and subtract $1$: $$(3k+2)(2j+1)-1=3(2jk+k)+4j+1$$

For this result to be a multiple of $3$, we need $4j+1$ to be a multiple of $3$. This happens for any $j$ that is one less than a multiple of $3$. If we require that $j\equiv 2\pmod 3$, that is the same as requiring that our odd number $2j+1\equiv 5\pmod 6$.

To summarize: the function *is* surjective. If $m$ is even, then we can take $k=1$. If $m$ is odd, then we can take $k=5$, or any other odd number congruent to $5$, modulo $6$.